# SystemGuid.Keyboard is freezing my Program

Tags: c#, keyboard, directx

I have the follow "Program"

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("buh");

    System.Guid key = SystemGuid.Keyboard;

    Console.WriteLine("By");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

If I set the line in, the Program is freezing and no Message is shown. 
If I start the program not from Visual Studio (just running the exe)

I get the follow message:

> Unbehandelte Ausnahme: System.IO.FileLoadException: Die Assembly im
>   gemischten Modus wurde während Version v1.1.4322 der Laufzeit erstellt
>   und kann nicht während der 4.0-Laufzeit ohne zusätzliche
>   Konfigurationsinformationen geladen werden. bei
>   ConsoleApplication3.Program.Main(String[] args)

How can I fix this.

Comment: This isn't a german site. Please try and translate your error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to version of referenced dll that you used. Just right click your project, choose properties and change .Net version to for example 3.5. Or add reference to newest version of directx dlls (if exist)